# nginx 403 forbidden under Debian 7

Tags: nginx, debian

I encounter a 403 forbidden error on my laptop with Debian 7

file permission is 775: `chmod 775 -R /var/www`

nginx error log shows:

> 2013/07/05 16:27:06 [error] 7351#0: *12 directory index of
> "/var/www/install/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server:
> localhost, request: "GET /install/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

phpinfo works fine

hereby my configuration:

**1, /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

> user www-data;
>
> worker_processes 1;
>
> pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
>
> events {
> worker_connections 768;
> # multi_accept on; }
>
> http {
>
> ```
> ##
> # Basic Settings
> ##
>
> sendfile on;
> tcp_nopush on;
> tcp_nodelay on;
> keepalive_timeout 65;
> types_hash_max_size 2048;
> # server_tokens off;
>
> # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
> # server_name_in_redirect off;
>
> include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
> default_type application/octet-stream;
>
> ##
> # Logging Settings
> ##
>
> access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
> error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
> include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
> include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; }
> ```

**2, /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

> server {
> listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
> #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
>
> ```
> #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
> root /var/www;
> index index.html index.php;
>
> # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
> server_name localhost;
> server_name_in_redirect off;
>
> location / {
>         # First attempt to serve request as file, then
>         # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
>         # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
>         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
>         # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
>         # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
> }
>
> location /doc/ {
>         alias /usr/share/doc/;
>         autoindex on;
>         allow 127.0.0.1;
>         allow ::1;
>         deny all;
> }
>
> # Rewrite for Fork CMS
> ```
>
> location ~ ^/(backend|install|api(/\d.\d)?(/client)?).*.php$ {
>
> ## backend/install/api are existing dirs, but should all pass via the front try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }
>
> location ~ ^(.+.php)(.*)$ {  include fastcgi_params;  fastcgi_pass
> 127.0.0.1:9000;  fastcgi_index index.php;  }
>
> ```
> # gzip
> ```
>
> gzip on;
> gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)"; # disables gzip compression for browsers that don't support it (in this case MS
> Internet Explorer before version 6 SV1).  gzip_http_version 1.1;
> gzip_vary on; # This sets the response header Vary: Accept-Encoding.
> Some proxies have a bug in that they serve compressed content to
> browsers that don't support it. By setting the Vary: Accept-Encoding
> header, you instruct proxies to store both a compressed and
> uncompressed version of the content.  gzip_comp_level 6;  gzip_proxied
> any;  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json
> application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss
> text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js ;  gzip_buffers 16
> 8k;
>
> ```
> # client caching  location ~   \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$
> { expires 31d; add_header Pragma "public"; add_header Cache-Control
> "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"; }
>
> # End of Fork
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `http://localhost/install` passes by the second rule of the `try_files` which is `$uri/` so it tries to access `install` as a folder, but you don't have `autoindex` on, so it fails with a forbidden error.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

I suggest removing the `$uri/` part.

```
try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad-AbuShady, it works. As you said  I don't have `autoindex` on, so I tried to put `autoindex on;` before `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting up WordPress running on nginx on a VPS, and was constantly getting a 403 forbidden error. Permissions all set correctly, everything looked fine, but still kept getting the 403.

For some reason, everyone suggested using this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

When I did as MAShady suggested above, and removed the `$uri/`, so it looked like this in my server block:

```
try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
```

...and amazingly, the configuration worked!

Truly amazing!

Many thanks!

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation